# battery status light flashing orange, what is it?

Tags: battery, dell-xps, status

The battery status light on my Studio XPS is blinking. 1 white, 4 orange.

What is the problem and how can I fix it or stop it?

The battery can only run for about 10 minutes without the AC adapter. I know I have to change the battery, but this is not possible for me right now.

Answer (score 4):

I expect it is telling you that the battery is no good and it is time to change it.

Answer (score 1):

As Xavierjazz answered, the battery is dead and needs to be replaced.  You can not fix it and you can not stop the blinking.  You *can* put tape over the lights if its bothering you.